# How to add a char to a map without turning to a number ? C++

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm trying to create a function that takes a series of two-letter inputs separated by whitespace, and add each input to a map where the first letter is a key and the second letter is a value.

For example, if my input was like this:

`ab cd ef gh ij`

My map should be like this:

```
['b' ,'a']
['d','c']
['f','e']
['h','g']
['j','i']
```

But what I'm getting is this instead:

```
[97 ,'a']
[99,'c']
[101,'e']
[103,'g']
[105,'i']
```

I'm also having another problem. When I try to run my program, it doesn't run the code below the loop and just stops running.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using std::string, std::cin, std::cout,  std::endl, std::istream, std::map;


std::map<char,char> encrypt(string const &inpt, map<char,char> &letter_pair){
    
    letter_pair[inpt.at(0)] = inpt.at(1);
    
    return letter_pair;
}

int main(){
    string input;
    
    map<char,char> letter_pair;
    while(cin >> input ){
        
        encrypt(input,letter_pair);

    }
    for(auto pos = letter_pair.begin(); pos != letter_pair.end();++pos){
        cout << pos->first <<":" << pos->second <<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Is this your real code and real output?  Your output has `[` and `,` and `]`, but I don't see how your code is producing that.

Comment: `char`s are numbers and 97 is `a` see [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii), it all depends on how you print them.

Comment: this is what I got when I used the debugger. I tried running the code from the terminal but for some reason it doesn't output anything

Comment: `'b'` is a character literal with the integer value of `98`. Different ways to visualize the same value. Hexadecimal, octal, or binary would be others. None changes the value, just shows it in a different way. The output I see here is what I would expect: https://godbolt.org/z/zWKxMGnrr

Comment: OT: You modify the map in-place, why do you return a *copy* of it? That you don't even use?

Comment: @ Richard Critten would that mean if I tried to look for the key b using find would I get an itr to the key ?

Comment: To be clear - you are not asking about the behavior of this program, you are asking about the way your debugger-of-choice displays your values?

Comment: Also note that you don't include all the required headers for all your symbols. For `std::string` you should always include `<string>`. And why are you `using std::vector`?

Comment: To be clear `char ch = 'a';` and `char ch = 97;` assign exactly the same value to `ch`.

Comment: I forgot to copy the first line of the code which is `#include <string>`,  but why my program is not running till the code below the loop ? why is it stopping ?

Comment: @ Some programmer dude what does it matter if Included `using std::vector` ?. I was building my program and I know that I'm going to use it later.

Comment: You have a loop that constantly reads input. The only way to break that loop as written is to generate an `EOF`. `ctrl+d` on Mac/Linux or `ctrl+z` on a blank line for Windows.

Comment: @Retired Ninja  I tried doing it that but it just stopped the program, I want it to go to the code below the while loop and output my map.

Comment: @Eleven Then you should ask the user to enter a sentinel value that the loop can look for to end itself, for example check `input` for `"stop"` before passing it to `encrypt()`, ie `ab cd ef gh ij stop` `while(cin >> input && input != "stop"){ ... }`

Comment: Please don't add things you don't need, even if you will use them later. Only add the things you need *when* you need them. That makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
std::map<char, char> database;
//...
database['a'] = 'b';
```

No need for using the ASCII numbers.

**Edit 1: A real program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<char, char> encryption_table;
    // Initialize
    encryption_table['a'] = 'b';
    encryption_table['c'] = 'd';

    // Print the encryption table.
    std::map<char, char>::const_iterator iter;
    std::map<char, char>::const_iterator iter_end = encryption_table.end();
    for (iter = encryption_table.begin();
         iter != iter_end;
         ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << '['  << iter->first
                  << ", " << iter->second
                  << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2: Building encryption table from User input**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<char, char> encryption_table;

    // Create the encryption table from User input
    char from_char;
    char to_char;
    while (std::cin >> from_char >> to_char)
    {
        encryption_table[from_char] = to_char;
    }

    // Print the encryption table.
    std::map<char, char>::const_iterator iter;
    std::map<char, char>::const_iterator iter_end = encryption_table.end();
    for (iter = encryption_table.begin();
         iter != iter_end;
         ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << '['  << iter->first
                  << ", " << iter->second
                  << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Run:**

```
tmatthews$ g++ main.cpp -o main.exe

tmatthews$ ./main.exe
ab cd ef
[a, b]
[c, d]
[e, f]
```

Comment: that would also work. but could you please how can I fix my program to make it output the code below the while loop?

Comment: @Eleven how do you want to indicate that you are done entering map values in a loop?

Comment: @Drew Dormann the input should be one line only and if that line end, the loop should stop.

Comment: @Eleven that won't work when using `operator>>` on `std::cin`, since `operator>>` swallows line breaks. You will have to instead read the whole line at one time using `std::getline()`, and then parse the inputs from that line, ie by using `operator>>` with a `std::istringstream`

Comment: @Thomas Matthews who would you do that if you had to get the input of the two letters from the user and knowing the input doesn't have fixed length ?

Comment: @Eleven: I just posted an example, #2, that inputs pairs of letters and builds the encryption table.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I think you gave me the answer that I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasMatthews your example suffers from the same problem - it doesn't know when to stop reading.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I just tested my input, and it is working.  The input loop will end when the User enters an "End of Data" character or signal.  I'm using Cygwin, so I did a Ctrl-D after the last letter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  I'm using the standard input pattern as shown in StackOverflow examples.  The code I posted doesn't care about line breaks.  The OP doesn't show any requirement for line input, only to read pairs of letters separated by whitespace.